# How to make RecyclerView behave like Paragraph?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to make view, where some lines are shown as a paragraph(i.e. not as a vertical list but as a paragraph). But I also want each of the line to be clickable, so that I can prompt the user to share that specific line (to highlight or copy etc).

I am actually building an app with translation. I want user to read the paragraph both standalone(1st image) and with translation. But I want the standalone version like the 1st image below, in a paragraph format. How to achieve that using `RecyclerView` (as I have already achieved translation version with RecyclerView)?

*On other words, I know how to use two views in a single RecyclerView*, but (see the 3-5 lines of first image) **how to warp one layout into other using RecyclerView**

**Edit:** I've tried `flexbox` layout, it doesn't satisfy my requirement.

[image]

Comment: You need a `ListView` with a custom `Adapter` and list item layout. See [here](https://medium.com/mindorks/custom-array-adapters-made-easy-b6c4930560dd).

Comment: @GavinWright
listview or recycler view, doesn't matter, i wanted detailed explanation for my specific question, the link you provided, doesn't satisfy my need, i already tried those

Comment: I don't fully understand the problem. I'm guessing you have an `ArrayList` of sentences and you want them arranged in paragraph form? You could create  `ArrayList<ArrayList<Sentence>>` and use that as the backing array for an Adapter. Each `ArrayList<Sentence>` represents a paragraph. And the `Adapter` simply concatenates all the `Sentence`s in a paragraph and displays them in a `TextView`.

Comment: @GavinWright no you didn't understand my question fully, but you are close...all i want is make a paragraph, not a list of paragraphs.....but each element of my paragraph must be a line, which is a layout(textview maybe) inflated using an adapter(either list/recycler)....i could just use a simple listview, like you said, but then, my sentences will not wrap with each other like a paragraph

Answer (score 1):

The answer is FlexBoxLayoutManager you can use it with RecyclerView put

```
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.0.0'
```

in your gradle file. Now setting up RecyclerView layout,

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    xmlns:toools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/end_indicator"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:textDirection="anyRtl"
    android:id="@+id/line_holder"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/line_holder"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/stackoverflow_bg"
    android:id="@+id/end_indicator"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

here stackoverflow_bg.xml is an oval shape drawable.
Now setting up RecyclerView,

```
 FlexboxLayoutManager manager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(this);
    manager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.CENTER);
    manager.setFlexWrap(FlexWrap.WRAP);
    manager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.ROW_REVERSE);
    rv.setLayoutManager(manager);
    rv.setAdapter(rvAdapter);
```

The layout I made:
[image: recyclerview]
As you can see this layout needs some working. The end indicator must be aligned to the last line of the TextView then it will fix the problem. Now you can even handle line click events as it is all done inside a Recyclerview.

Comment: "What you're trying to achieve is, RecyclerView having lines of a paragraph and when the user clicks on a line you want to show options for that line, right?"
yes and the lines should be formatted just like the paragraph not any vertical listview

Comment: To help you I need to know the format of data you're receiving, the model class and the adapter

Comment: just guess I have a model to represent single sentences....nothing fancy here, all i want is the idea how to achieve what i asked for, if it solves my purpose, will accept the answer, no question asked

Comment: I suppose you've got the 1st image already set up and you want to push in the 2nd image as translation for a line.

Comment: To do this use multiple views in Recyclerview or replace the line with the translation, saying you have the position of the line to be translated remove the original line from the ArrayList and user arrayList.add(pos, translatedLine) and then notify data set change.

Comment: "I suppose you've got the 1st image already set up and you want to push in the 2nd image as translation for a line."
No, its actually the opposite, i can make 2nd view, but can't make first.... i know how to use two views in a single recyclerview, but, see the 3-5 lines of first image, how to warp one layout into other using recyclerview

Comment: It is easy, use only textView in Recycler layout and center the TextView and add start and end padding to Recyclerview tag. Now use spannable string to populate the TextView.

Comment: i think your reply is heading to the right direction....can you please give me any example of what you just proposed editing you actual reply? or any resource to study?